# How can you override the base layout for specific controllers or actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a base layout in my application.html.erb file that is used for showing the layout for many pages in my app. I need to add another page in one of these controllers but I need it to use a different layout, not application.html.erb. How do I override this on a per action and  controller basis?

Comment: The heading and body of your question are different. What are you after? override a layout for all actions in a controller (in which case see fwidtmann's answer) or overrirde a layout for a specific action within a controller (in which case see Baldrick's answer). Please edit your question appropriately

Comment: I wanted to know how to achieve both. Edited question to reflect the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use **layout** in your controller.rb

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
   layout 'application2' # application2.html.erb
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following line in the action

```
render layout: "my_specific_layout"
```